# Can triethylamine be substituted for pyridine as a base catalyst in acryloylation reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, polymers

I work in a polymer research lab and I'm writing a procedure to synthesize glycerol 1,3 diacrylate but in almost all the reactions I've been reading, the synthesis occurs at hot temperatures(60 C) and using pyridine.

We already synthesize poly(glycerol-co-sebacate) acrylate and in that procedure, we found that it works best using triethylamine and acryloyl chloride at cold temperatures(0 C) due to higher reactivity, so I'm wondering if pyridine can be substituted with triethylamine at colder temperatures for the glycerol 1,3 diacrylate synthesis.

In my head, I think that it should work since the role for both in their respective reactions is as a base catalyst with the main difference being that triethylamine is much more reactive than pyridine but if anyone else can give their two-sense on the matter that would be very much appreciated.

Thank you!!

Comment: Without additional info nobody here can say for sure. The proper way to go is to perform both experiments and compare yield, reaction time and product purity. In general one can say, that pyridine is less nucleophilic and less volatile. The first property is often desired, the second not such much. On the other hand, pyridine can also be used as a polar solvent or as a catalyst for acylation reactions. What this means for your system has be evaluated by yours on the basis of multiple experiments and evaluation of the same.